# QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread

Tags: multithreading, qt

I'm trying to handle a message that is received over a serial port in a concurrent manner. That is for each message that requires processing I want to use a different thread.

To do so I use the following code where  `receive_Message` is connected to a signal that is emited for each message.

```
void Bat::receivePWrapper(Bat* bat, Message msg){
        bat->process_Message(msg);
    }
void Bat::receive_Message(Message msg){
       QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(Bat::receivePWrapper,this,msg);
   }
```

It apparently works but I get the message `QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread` for each message I receive.

The `process_Message` function manipulates GUI objects. Is that the issue here?

Comment: Some where in the code [`QObject::startTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) is being called from a thread *other* than the thread associated with the `QObject` itself -- probably as a result of a call to `QTimer::start`.  If you're using `QTimer`s anywhere you need to show the relevant code.

Comment: @G.M. I am not, might be called by one of the Qt GUI objects.

Comment: If the timer isn't in your own code then your best bet would be to get/build a debug version of the Qt libraries and set a breakpoint on the line that issues the warning (line 1643 of qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp in the linux qt5.8 sources) and have a look at the back trace at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that runs in a secondary process must not access any GUI objects directly.

It can either emit signals connected to slots of these objects or use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` with connection type `Qt::QueuedConnection` to delegate the GUI object method call to the main thread.